# Restoring samba mappings after reboot?

Tags: networking, samba

I've setup a simple Ubuntu 10.04 file server and want to have a handful of users attach from windows machine to a Shared drive and to private Home directories on a per machine basis.

I've got this all setup and have mapped the drives within windows (Shared = Z:, Home = H:) on one of the machines and everything works fine. However when I restart the user machine they are still able to access the shared drive, but when trying to open their Home drive I get the error,

`An error occured while reconnecting H: to \\Server01\homes Microsoft Window Network: The network name cannot be found. This connection has not been restore`

If I then disconnect from the Home and Shared drive and reconnect then everything work fine, until I have to reboot the machine again!

Any ideas why this is happening and how I can get round it?

---

OK so I've made a little progress. If instead of mapping to the \Server01\homes directory I map to the \Server01\username directory, then I don't get the error message like before. However it does say:

`Incorrect password or unknown username for: \\Server01\username`

If I enter the exact same password as before then I connect fine, but I'd rather not have to force my users to enter a password each time the machine is started.

Comment: Is the user/pass you use for logging in to windows the same as you use with samba?

Comment: There are no logins to the windows machines.

Answer (score 2):

To me this looks more a Windows issue than an Ubuntu one: I suspect the Windows client is trying to connect with the wrong password (or no password at all) to the `\server01\homes` share.

IIRC, right after login, Windows will try connecting to authenticated shares using the same username/password combination that was used for logging in; if the username/password combination used on Windows does not match what the SAMBA server running on Ubuntu expects, the share will not be mounted because of an authentication error.  (I think this is what SourceLab was hinting to in his comment.)

Comment: I agree.  It sounds like the Windows box is trying to use Windows logon credentials to access the network share.  This is the default mode of authentication in Windows.